# can I passing Control Template to external dll?

Tags: c#, controltemplate, powerbuilder

I have creating control template in PB.net and now I want to create external function at Video Studio by using C# to apply that template in Group box control I creating in code behind. Anyone have an idea on how can I passing that template

Here my XAML control template in Powerbuilder.net

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="GBTemplate" TargetType="GroupBox">
```

Here my C# code behind:

```
    public void ResourceTemplate(ControlTemplate GBTemplate)
    {
        GroupBox gb1 = new GroupBox();
        gb1.Template=Resources["GBTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
plat.Children.Add(gb1);
    }
```

I got an issue where name 'Resource' do not exist in the current context.

Comment: Video Studio? PowerBuilder? I have no idea what you're talking about. Is this WPF?

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this before but looking at your code it looks like you are adding the control template to a group box that you are creating inside your function. I'm assuming that you want to assign it to a group box that is already instantiated and lives on the windows somewhere.

So essentially if your group box on the window is named gb_1 remove the definition and new-up of groupbox and do gb_1.Template= ...

This is just a guess the code looks suspect because you are creating the group box within the function.

OR *maybe* you could over-ride the OnApplyTemplate something like:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate() {
   base.OnApplyTemplate();

    this.Template=... 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing but actually I plan to create groupbox in that function and applying template on it. Since I  create new groupbox in function, it do not detect Resources

Comment: Wish I knew more about WPF but kinda weak in that area... good luck